# I have a Wordpress custom post type, and a page dedicated to showing all of them; but because of sharing 'news' in their URL, I've got an error

Tags: php, wordpress

*I'm just learning WP, so please don't attack as it's a **noob question***.

**My story**:

I created a WP page and selected `News` through the `Template` dropdown. I typed "News" as the title, and some text inside the WYSIWYG editor as the content, so it creates a page with this URL obviously: `http://localhost:8012/wordpress/news/`. It's a page dedicated to showing all my `news` custom post types, thanks to the file `template-news.php`:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: News
*/

get_header();

query_posts(array(
   'post_type' => 'news'
)); ?>
<?php
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
<?php endwhile;

get_footer();
?>
```

As I said, I have one WP custom post type (let's call it `news` post from now on), so here's the code;

`functions.php`:

```
<?php
  function my_custom_menu() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'my-custom-menu' => _( 'My Custom Menu' ),
            'my-custom-menu-2' =>_('My Second Custom Menu')
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_menu' );

function create_posttype() {
    register_post_type( 'news',
    // CPT Options
    array(
      'labels' => array(
       'name' => __( 'news' ),
       'singular_name' => __( 'News' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => false,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'news'),
     )
    );
    }
    // Hooking up our function to theme setup
    add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );


    
function cw_post_type_news() {
    $supports = array(
    'title', // post title
    'editor', // post content
    'author', // post author
    'thumbnail', // featured images
    'excerpt', // post excerpt
    'custom-fields', // custom fields
    'comments', // post comments
    'revisions', // post revisions
    'post-formats', // post formats
    );
    $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('news', 'plural'),
    'singular_name' => _x('news', 'singular'),
    'menu_name' => _x('news', 'admin menu'),
    'name_admin_bar' => _x('news', 'admin bar'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'add new'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New news'),
    'new_item' => __('New news'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit news'),
    'view_item' => __('View news'),
    'all_items' => __('All news'),
    'search_items' => __('Search news'),
    'not_found' => __('No news found.'),
    );
    $args = array(
    'supports' => $supports,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'news'),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    );
    register_post_type('news', $args);
    }
    add_action('init', 'cw_post_type_news');
?>
```

`single-news.php`:

```
<?php
get_header();
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
   get_template_part('template-parts/post/content', get_post_format());
   the_title();
endwhile;
get_footer();
?>
```

**My problem**:

So far we have `news` custom post type, and a `news` page. And when I want to add a new `news` post, and for example name it `news-1`, it's created with the URL, `http://localhost:8012/wordpress/news/news-1/`, so I can view the post with `single-news.php` structure, and it's fine. But... when I want to see the `news` page itself which has the URL, `http://localhost:8012/wordpress/news/` (as I said above), it takes me back to the home page (`index.php`). However, when I changed the permalink of `news` page to everything else, for example `article`, it works fine and with the URL, `http://localhost:8012/wordpress/article/`, I can see all `news` posts under the `template-news.php` sturcture, and clicking on each post takes me to the post itself under the `single-news.php` structure!

What's the solution to this weird problem? Thanks!

Comment: If you had set `has_archive` to true, then `/news/` would be the archive page URL for this CPT. Since you set it to false, so that this CPT will not have an archive page, I suppose it'll redirect you to the index then. Probably best - and easiest - would be to avoid that overlap between CPT slug, and existing page name, altogether in the first place - by naming one of them something else. You could of course also set the CPT to _have_ an archive - and then create an archive template specifically for this CPT, that shows something else.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment! You mean I have to set "has_archive" to "true", and then create an archive page for it?
Edit: Thanks! Now it works!

Comment: An archive _template_, so that when the "archive" for your CPT is shown when just the base slug is requested, it will show the content from that template. (If you want to show a specific post only then in that template , you'll either have to write a custom query, or use the pre_get_posts filter to manipulate the query for this archive.)